# EKS node unable to connect to RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have an EKS cluster where I have a Keycloak service that is trying to connect to RDS within the same VPC.
I have also added a inbound rule to the RDS Security Group which allow postgresql from source `eksctl-prod-cluster-ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXXX`

When the application tries to connect to RDS i get the following message:

`timeout reached before the port went into state "inuse"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the inbound rule on the `RDS Security Group` from the `eksctl-prod-cluster-ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup-XXXXXXXXX` with an inbound rule allowing access from the EKS VPC CIDR address instead.